# ValueAnimator slow in Android in heavy layout

Tags: c#, android, animation, xamarin

I use from Xamarin, and C#
animation is slow in main layout

On the top of my form exist 7 TextView. And I fill thease on the code with spannable (change font, color, size)

On the bottom of form, main menu exist.
When I use animation in main menu, animation is very slow. (ValueAnimator)

When visibility=gone textviews, animation is OK

I test SetLayerType (LayerType.None, null) and DrawingCacheEnabled
but not effect.

What's wrong?

```
ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.OfInt(0, 240);
animator.SetDuration(200);
animator.Start();
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams Params2 = ((RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)imgMenuSelectBack.LayoutParameters);
int ML = Params2.LeftMargin;
animator.Update += (s, ee) =>
{
    int newValue = ML - (int)ee.Animation.AnimatedValue;
    Params2.SetMargins(newValue, 0, 0, 0);
    imgMenuSelectBack.LayoutParameters = Params2;
};
```

Comment: `ValueAnimator` is not slow, what can be slow is your code called inside `ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener`

Comment: I know ValueAnimator not slow. Animation work fast when textview in page visibility=gone. my textview not in cache. and i cant cache textview